# An user access to session of another user

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, session, nginx

Good evening, I tell you my problem. I have an application developed in PHP with Codeigniter running on a web hosting in Wiroos. Everything was working correctly, but as time passed, the application had more users who accessed simultaneously (obviously) and the following problem began to occur.

When user A logs in from location A, a session A is generated. If at the same time user B from location B accesses the application, user A's session is automatically loaded into its location B ... as it can Is this possible?

I show you the code of my application to see if you can help me

**Login Controller**

```
public function index($estadoLogin = 0){

if($this->session->userdata('estado_sesion'))
{
    redirect(base_url()."panel");
}
$data['estadoLogin'] = $estadoLogin;
$data['title'] = "Iniciar Sesión - LandingApp";
$data['bodyClass'] = "external-page sb-l-c sb-r-c";

$this->load->view('templates/header',$data);        
$this->load->view('login/loginbox', $data);

}//End method index
```

**Login Method**

```
public function ingresar(){
$correo = $this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('correo')));
$pass = md5($this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('password'))));

$Usuarios = new Usuario_Model();
$result = $Usuarios->login($correo, $pass);
if(count($result)>0){
    foreach($result as $u){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('mail');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('nombre');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('activo');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logo_empresa');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('nombre_empresa');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('id_empresa');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('nivel');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('estado_sesion');

        $this->session->set_userdata('id', $u->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('mail', $u->mail);
        $this->session->set_userdata('nombre', $u->nombre);
        $this->session->set_userdata('activo', $u->activo);
        $this->session->set_userdata('nivel', $u->nivel);
        $this->session->set_userdata('nombre_empresa', $u->nombre_empresa);
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_empresa', $u->id_empresa);
        $this->session->set_userdata('logo_empresa', $u->logo_empresa);
        $this->session->set_userdata('avatar_user', $u->avatar_user);
        $this->session->set_userdata('estado_sesion', TRUE);

        redirect(base_url()."panel");

    }//End foreach


}else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensaje', 'El usuario o password es incorrecto');
    redirect(base_url()."login/index/1");
    //$this->index(1);
}//End if
```

**Panel Controller**

```
public function index(){


$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$id_empresa = $this->session->userdata('id_empresa');

$data_session['title'] = "Panel General";
$data_session['opcionMenu'] = "panel";
$data_session['bodyClass'] = "dashboard-page";

$data_session = $this->session_data_lib->set_data_session($data_session); //cargo las variables de sesion

if ($data_session['nivel']==1 || $data_session['nivel']==2){

    $data_counters = $this->counters_lib->get_admin_counters(); //cargo las variables de contadores

}else{
    $data_counters = $this->counters_lib->get_user_counters(); //cargo las variables de contadores
}

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data_session);
$this->load->view('templates/menu_top', $data_session);
$this->load->view('templates/menu_left', $data_counters);
if ($data_session['nivel']==0) {
    $this->load->view('panel/panel_user',$data_counters);
}else{
    $this->load->view('panel/panel_admin',$data_counters);
}

$this->load->view('templates/footer',$data_counters);

}//End method index
```

**Session_Data_lib > set_data_session**

```
public function set_data_session($data_session){
$data_lib_session['title'] = $data_session['title'];
$data_lib_session['opcionMenu'] = $data_session['opcionMenu'];
$data_lib_session['bodyClass'] = $data_session['bodyClass']; 
$data_lib_session['nombre'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nombre');
$data_lib_session['userid'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('id');
$data_lib_session['nivel'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nivel');   
$data_lib_session['avatar_user'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('avatar_user');
$data_lib_session['logo_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('logo_empresa');
$data_lib_session['nombre_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nombre_empresa');
$data_lib_session['id_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('id_empresa');
$data_lib_session['arr_css'] = array("absolute_admin/assets/fonts/iconsweets/iconsweets.css");
$data_lib_session['lastSegs'] = $this->CI->panel_model->get10LastSeg($this->CI->session->userdata('id_empresa'));

return $data_lib_session;
}//End method set_data_session
```

I tried to migrate Codeigniter to version 3.0, and even make the following configuration in application / config / config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I do not know what else to try, I have the feeling that it can be a server configuration, but I still had no response from the support other than this:

> Our servers have a micro-cache layer managed by nginx that may have
>   caused this behavior, now I deactivated it for your domain. Could you
>   please try it again?

Obviously the problem persists. I do not understand how it can be that two different users from different locations can access the session of the other at the time that both are consulting the server. I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: `$pass = md5(...)` MD5 hashing is no longer considered secure, and you should think about changing to use `password_hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  Also in your login page all this functionality should be wrapped up in the user model instead of half of it.

Comment: I have reviewed you code the best I can given the information above.  Now it's time for bed.

Comment: Artistic Phoenix, thanks for your reply! I will try to test your answer, but problems are the sessions probably, not login logic. I will reply to you as soon as possible

Comment: hash_password instead of md5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. Problem was is micro-cache layer managed by NGINX. My hosting support disabled that and all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments you should update your passwords to use PHP's `hash_password` instead of `md5`

I can't say this is your issue, but you should verify that you do not have duplicate data in your users table.  This code

```
public function ingresar(){
   $correo = $this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('correo')));
   $pass = md5($this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('password'))));
```

Specifically

```
$this->input->post('correo')
```

CI can return `FALSE` if the data is not set in the `$_POST` so if there is a problem you're are not checking if you are using `FALSE` for either one or both the password and the email.  You should be checking like this, for example

```
public function ingresar(){
  if(!$this->input->post('correo'))
       //throw an error - stop execution, etc.
  if(!$this->input->post('password'))
       //throw an error - stop execution, etc.

  /* ...continue on if both inputs are valid ... */
```

If you do not have unique fields set in your Database, you could have dozens of duplicate users with the same password and email. Both set to `false`

I can't tell this without knowing what constraints you have set on your DB fields for the user table.  But, if you don't have the proper constraints then it may be possible to have multiple users with a password of `false` and an email of `false`  ( at least according to your login code ) which would pass into your database lookup and pull multiple results.

The only way to know for sure is to look in PhpMyAdmin, at your user table, and see if you have duplicate passwords and emails in there.

Also in line with multiple users, you are not restricting login to 1 account only. Consider this part of your code.

```
public function ingresar(){
    /* ..... */
    if(count($result)>0){  //should expect only one user returned.
        foreach($result as $u){
```

A loop here implies we are expecting one or more return records. This should throw an error if more then 1 user is returned.  Emails should be unique and we should never have 2 or more users returned when looking up a user by his email. ( again without seeing the implementation of your User Model I can only guess ).  But you should be explicitly checking like this:

```
public function ingresar(){
    /* ..... */
    if(count($result)==1){ 
     //log user in
    }else if(count($result)>1){
       //this should never happen but it is, so you should pay attention here
    }else{
       //user not found or wrong password.
    }
```

Something that could happen with the loop you have there, is that the session data will be overwritten until the last duplicate record.  So everyone with a 'bad' account gets logged in as the last record pulled by the bad email data.

All in all I would say there are a lot of "holes" in your code that could allow this to happen under the right conditions.  Most of this is "Guesses" based of what I can see an the loose constraints you have in place for login.  The login is the gateway to your application and should be buttoned down much tighter then this.

PS. I used google translate, so I hope I read everything correctly.